# How to hide data on column name company Name based on field name Company Name?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I face issue : I can't make column Name company Name hide data

where field Name of report Control json is Company Name .

report control is table have field Name.

Based on Field Name value I will hide  data on column Assigned to Field Name .

```
          <ng-container *ngFor="let repcon of ReportControl">

                      <div *ngIf="coln==repcon.fieldName">

                     
                      </div>
                    </ng-container>
```

stack blitz I work on it as below and it have all data related and code :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-z4aduq?file=app/app.component.html

On component.ts

repcon return data for report control as below :

report control is :

```
[{"reportId":2028,"fieldName":"companyName","columnType":1}]
```

Expected result as you see below company name is empty :

[image: hide data on column name Company Name based on column Company Name]

can there are any way can do that by dynamic way
I use field Name to can use it control based on field name exist
then i can use it .

why not like below :

```
*ngIf="coln==repcon.fieldName
```

what I need to achieve as Image below display :
[image: hide data based on field Name for report control table]

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: thank you for reply yes but this is static way I need it dynamic meaning I use Field Name to be dynamic can you help me do that really I ask for to be dynamic way so that I use Field Name

Comment: meaning can i do coln != 'fieldName'

Comment: can you see updated post . by any way I can accept any solution help me to be dynamic

Comment: thank you for reply I write  hide company name because it exist on field name for report control array of object . solution is static but i need it dynamic to be based on field name from report control array of object

Comment: thank you for reply What I need to do is hide data based on field Name but not rename column with field Name see above I updated My post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question the solution:

if you just hide companyName column values use below:

```
<span *ngIf="coln != 'companyName'" >
   {{rep[coln]}}
</span>
```

if you only change header 'companyName' to 'fieldName' you just change

```
<div>{{coln}}</div>
```

to

```
<div>{{coln == "companyName" ? "fieldName" : coln}}</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can i change companyName to fieldName or not

Comment: erata are this possible or not

Comment: i  changed the answer as i understand.

Comment: can you see image above this actually what I need to do based on fieldName I will hide column that exist on field Name table report control  after that if exist on report control fieldName it will be hide data for columns related